# MVC server-side validation on decimal values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, decimal, server-side

I've got a problem with validating a model server-side in MVC. My model has a number of fields and every single one of them validates fine. The only problem I have is with two decimal fields:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Currency]
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)]
public decimal A { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)]
public Nullable<decimal> B { get; set; }
```

If the value is null for A or a string for A or B I get a NullReferenceException with a stacktrace I can't even analyze. I try to catch the exception in my controller, but the exception appears before it gets there. 
If I but a number value in A and leave a null or put a number in B (just like both would be valid), everything else goes as expected - if there are validation problems they are displayed, if not the record is saved in the DB. 
I've tried looking everywhere, but maybe I overlooked something... Besides I've gotten a bit rusty and validation was never my strong side.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Remove `[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)]` from A (its not a nullable type so this make no sense and cant be done - just let the `Required` attribute take care of the validation

Comment: I tried without displayformat, with the required only, but still throws an exception